# Unwrap a list of list

Tags: python, parsing, list-comprehension

I have this list:

```
fxrate = 
[[['9.6587'], ['9.9742'], ['9.9203'], ['10.1165'], ['10.1087']],
 [['10.7391'], ['10.8951'], ['11.1355'], ['11.561'], ['11.7873']],
 [['8.61'], ['8.9648'], ['9.0155'], ['9.153'], ['9.1475']]]
```

I would like to make a list like this by using Python:

```
[[9.6587, 9.9742, 9.9203, 10.1165, 10.1087],
 [10.7391, 10.8951, 11.1355, 11.561, 11.7873],
 [8.61, 8.9648, 9.0155, 9.153, 9.1475]]
```

Needless to say I'm fairly new to Python and programming in general. However all I end up with is either one list of values but not at three sets of lists

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is flatten your list,
Just use a list comprehension.
This will take any list of lists you have and flatten it such that,
Your list only has a depth of one.
i.e. `[["foo"], ["bar"],["List_of_lists"]]` would become `["foo", "bar", "complex_lists"]`

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

As specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

You can format this into your code as necessary.
Like so:

```
fxrate = 
   [[['9.6587'], ['9.9742'], ['9.9203'], ['10.1165'], ['10.1087']],
   [['10.7391'], ['10.8951'], ['11.1355'], ['11.561'], ['11.7873']],
   [['8.61'], ['8.9648'], ['9.0155'], ['9.153'], ['9.1475']]]
flat_fxrate = [[item for sublist in fxrate[0] for item in sublist],[item for sublist in fxrate[1] for item in sublist],[item for sublist in fxrate[2] for item in sublist]]
```

For example. Since you want it split in three or if you plan to upscale it. Or to make it more legible, you can use a loop and append each part. Like so. Note: In general it's a lot better to use a loop because then no matter what the size of this list is, it will always work.

```
flat_fxrate = []
fxrate = 
   [[['9.6587'], ['9.9742'], ['9.9203'], ['10.1165'], ['10.1087']],
   [['10.7391'], ['10.8951'], ['11.1355'], ['11.561'], ['11.7873']],
   [['8.61'], ['8.9648'], ['9.0155'], ['9.153'], ['9.1475']]]
for x in fxrate:
    flat_fxrate.append([item for sublist in x for item in sublist])
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I wanted to do! I was not able to get it to work with the other solutions that was presented, but this did the trick!